# Excel VBA Calendar - pick up date command problem

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on my first VBA project and I am really stuck.

On my Excel sheet I need a Date Picker. The Excel version I am using does not have one, so I created my own calendar using the code from the link below ( The one created by L42, with the 42 labels and so on):

[Formatting MM/DD/YYYY dates in textbox in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba)

The calendar looks just like the one in the image, so all good so far.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqSd2.png)

On my Excel spreadsheet I added a code which makes the calendar pop up only in  two cells, E2 and F2, which represent the start date and the end date for my data.

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E2"), target) Is Nothing Then
MyCalendar.Show
End If
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("F2"), target) Is Nothing Then
MyCalendar.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Everything works fine, the calendar only pops up when I click on these two cells only. 
So, when I click on E2, the calendar pops up, I select a date, then a message box with the selected date pops up, I click ok to close it, then I close the calendar, but the date I clicked on will not be inserted in my E2 cell.

I guess I need a code in the select_label procedure below which will make the date I click on in the calendar and pops up in the MsgBox actually fill my excel E2 or F2 cells.

```
    Private Sub select_label(msForm_C As MSForms.Control)
        '/* Capture the selected date */
        Dim i As Integer, sel_date As Date
        i = Split(msForm_C.Name, "_")(1) - 1
        sel_date = FirstCalSun(curMonth) + i

        '/* Transfer the date where you want it to go */
        MsgBox sel_date

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what is `Cell`? Make sure you use `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: @Peh: Cell refers to the cell in my excel spreadsheet where my calendar pops up when I click on it.

Comment: No it does not refer to anything yet. At least you didn't show that reference in your code. Do you have `Option Explicit` activated?

Comment: You are right, it should refer to cells E2 and F2 from my workbook.Yes, I have it activated.

Comment: If it is activated then `Cell.Value` should throw an error. Have a look here [Calling a userform and returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966137/calling-a-userform-and-returning-a-value). That technique should solve your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a userform and returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966137/calling-a-userform-and-returning-a-value)